# Приставки в слове "предприниматель"

Tags: морфемика, морфемный-разбор, приставка

Какие есть приставки в слове *предприниматель* и есть ли они вообще?

Answer (score 2):

Согласно Морфемно-орфографическому словарю А. Тихонова в слове **предприним/а́/тель/** приставка не выделяется, т. е. произошло упрощение основы.